# I cant play minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant play minecraft because on the new launcher for 1.7.2, I keep hitting play, and the launcher vanishes for a little, and I think that minecraft is going to appear. Then, the launcher comes right back and appears again, and when I go to the Development Console, it says that its ignoring the invisibility rule due to game crash!

Comment: Re-install the launcher? I've seen that happen sometimes when something went weird with the game files.

Comment: This question is effectively "Minecraft crashes on launch" (all of the rest of the body is just the way the launcher reacts to any kind of game crash), which is far too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend a complete reinstallation.

Save your worlds somewhere else, delete all MC files, reinstall, and copy your saved worlds back in.

If this doesn't work, attempt a 3rd party MC launcher (Magic Launcher etc). Sometimes java apps can be a bit buggy.

If neither of these suggestions help, try contacting Mojang.